# LINQ GroupBy except null values

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

My aim is to list out duplicates, here's what I'm trying:

```cs
var duplicates = result
                 .GroupBy(x => x.col1)
                 .SelectMany(y => y.Count() > 1 ? y.Where(z => z.col2== decimal.Zero) : y)
                 .AsEnumerable()
                 .ToList();
```

but it's been grouped by all `null` values in `col1`.

#### Sample input

```
| col1   | col2   |
|--------|--------|
| 1/1/21 | 0.00   |
| 2/1/21 | 120.00 |
| 2/1/21 | 0.00   |
| 3/1/21 | 110.00 |
| null   | 140.00 |
| null   | 220.00 |
| 6/1/21 | 0.00   |
| 6/1/21 | 0.00   |
| 7/1/21 | 0.00   |
| null   | 0.00   |
|--------|--------|
```

#### Desired output

```
| col1   | col2   |
|--------|--------|
| 1/1/21 | 0.00   |
| 2/1/21 | 120.00 |
| 3/1/21 | 110.00 |
| null   | 140.00 |
| null   | 220.00 |
| 6/1/21 | 0.00   |
| 7/1/21 | 0.00   |
| null   | 0.00   |
|--------|--------|
```

Comment: Maybe `result.Where(x => x.col1 != null).GroupBy(x => x.col1)...`?

Comment: Could you please share with us your data model?

Comment: please see the edit

Comment: @MK88 If you have a duplicate like `2/1/21` or `6/1/21` then which one should we preserve?

Comment: GroupBy(col1), but except null values in col1.

Answer (score 1):

For selecting duplicates this query should work:

```cs
var duplicates = result
   .GroupBy(x => x.col1)
   .Where(y => y.Count() > 1)
   .SelectMany()
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `GroupBy()`, you need to handle the case where `col1` is null and assign a unique value for the group key. A `Guid` would do the job well. Try this:

```
var duplicates = result
                 .GroupBy(x => x.col1 == null ? Guid.NewGuid().ToString() : x.col1)
                 .Select(x => x.First())
                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Sample data

Let's suppose your domain model looks similar to this:

```cs
class DomainModel
{
    public string Col1 { get; }
    public double Col2 { get; }

    public DomainModel(string col1, double col2)
    {
        Col1 = col1;
        Col2 = col2;
    }
}
```

For testing purposes I will use the following List (populated with your sample input):

```cs
var result = new List<DomainModel>
{
    new DomainModel("1/1/21", 0.00),
    new DomainModel("2/1/21", 120.00),
    new DomainModel("2/1/21", 0.00),
    new DomainModel("3/1/21", 110.00),
    new DomainModel(null, 140.00),
    new DomainModel(null, 220.00),
    new DomainModel("6/1/21", 120.00),
    new DomainModel("6/1/21", 0.00),
    new DomainModel("7/1/21", 0.00),
    new DomainModel(null, 0.00)
};
```

#### Group adjacent records

If we can rely on the ordering then we can group the adjacent records which has the same `Col1`. To do this we need to use the [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/).

```cs
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, DomainModel>> groupedResult = result.GroupAdjacent(c => c.Col1);
```

Now if we would print out the `groupedResult` with the following command:

```cs
foreach (var group in groupedResult)
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key ?? "null");
    foreach (var model in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\t{model.Col2}");
    }
}
```

then we would see the following output:

```
1/1/21
        0
2/1/21
        120
        0
3/1/21
        110
null
        140
        220
6/1/21
        120
        0
7/1/21
        0
null
        0
```

#### Filter out unnecessary items

If I understand your requirements correctly then you want:

- Show all entries from those group where the key is `null`
- Show all groups which has a single entry
- Show only those entries where the `col2` is not 0 and there are more entries in the group

These can be translated into the following query:

```cs
var filteredResult = groupedResult.SelectMany(@group =>
    @group.Key == null
        ? @group //If col1 is null then return as is
        : @group.Count() == 1
            ? @group //If there is a single entry in a group then return as is
            : @group.Where(c => Math.Abs(c.Col2) > 0.01)); //If there are multiple entries then return those where col2 is not 0
```

If we execute this query the output will be as desired:

```cs
foreach (DomainModel model in filteredResult)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{model.Col1 ?? "null"} \t {model.Col2}");
}
```

```
1/1/21   0
2/1/21   120
3/1/21   110
null     140
null     220
6/1/21   120
7/1/21   0
null     0
```